# Phase of this AC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, phase, phasor, phase-shift

What will be the phase of the current trough the coil:

[image]

I think that I can find it using:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_\text{L}\right)=\arg\left\{\frac{230\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi\text{j}}{2}}}{\left(5+\frac{8\cdot9\text{j}}{8+9\text{j}}\right)}\cdot\frac{8}{8+9\text{j}}\right\}=\arctan\left(\frac{40}{117}\right)
\approx18,875^\circ$$

Where \$230\$ is the effective input voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the resistors to one value using [Thevenin's Theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html). In simple terms this is the parallel combination of R1 and R2 = 3.0769 ohms. The reactance is simply 9 ohms at 50 Hz and is in-series with the new value of resistor.

The combined impedance is 3.0769 + j9 or \$9.511\space \Omega \space \angle{71.125}\$

This means the current lags the input voltage by 71.125 degrees.

Comment: Yes, so when I put the voltage on the positive imaginary axis, then the current will be 18.875 degrees above the positive real axis?! (With other words 71.125 behind the voltage)

Comment: I prefer my explanation!!!

Comment: Ok, but is it wrong what I said?

Comment: If you want to regard the input voltage as leading by 90 degrees then the answer you have agrees with my answer.